# Zabbix alert event generation mode and multiple OK event generation

Tags: monitoring, zabbix

I have a trigger with:

- PROBLEM event generation mode: Multiple
- OK event closes: All problems

That trigger fires at the expression for the trapper item, which's updated by the crontab multiple times a day. Every time trapper gets a new value, it should be reported by the alert (cause' every time it gets a different value, which is important). But when it's OK, one message should be enough.

Action has "Send message to user groups" operation with a single step, "Immediately" start option and "Default" step duration (3600s).
Recovery operation set to "Send message to user groups" option.

Action also has only folowing conditions in the drop-down:

- Application
- Host
- Host group
- Maintenance status
- Tag
- Tag value
- Template
- Time period
- Trigger
- Trigger name
- Trigger severity

What may be the reason for multiple duplicating alert messages with OK status, coming at the same moment from the same trigger (and the same alert)?

Comment: What conditions does the action have?

Comment: @Richlv, it has a custom expression for lots of triggers like this `A or ((B or C) and (D or E or F or G or H or I or J or K))`

Comment: Do you have event type condition limiting to "PROBLEM" in the action? If not, you both react to "OK" events and send recovery messages - a highly confusing combo. Try either adding such a condition or not using recovery messages.

Comment: @Richlv updated the question

Comment: I'm having the same problem. Did you manage to solve it?

Comment: @Bluewind nope, still having this pain in the a

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried global event correlation ?

> It is possible to correlate events created by completely different
>   triggers and apply the same operations to them all. By creating
>   intelligent correlation rules it is actually possible to save yourself
>   from thousands of repetitive notifications and focus on root causes of
>   a problem!

https://www.zabbix.com/documentation/3.4/manual/config/event_correlation/global

Comment: How would this work? Simply letting the correlation close the old event also generates an OK notification. You could let it close the new event, but then you don't get notified about the new error.